# Gatsby Develop failing : Error: Cannot find module 'gatsby-cli/lib/reporter'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

Keep getting an error from gatsby-cli when doing gatsby develop command in terminal.

Already deleted node-modules and reinstalled using npm. Tried installing Gatsby-Cli as a separate module but that just causes more gatsby-cli errors. Gatsby-cli is a module inside the gatsby module, but I .really don't know why it's causing this error all of a sudden.

```
$ gatsby develop

success open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.054 s
error Error in


  Error: Cannot find module 'gatsby-cli/lib/reporter'

  - loader.js:582 Function.Module._resolveFilename
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15

  - loader.js:508 Function.Module._load
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25

  - loader.js:637 Module.require
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17

  - v8-compile-cache.js:159 require
    [Webmaster-Portfolio]/[v8-compile-cache]/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20

  - utils.js:15 Object.<anonymous>
    [Webmaster-Portfolio]/[gatsby-source-filesystem]/utils.js:15:18

  - v8-compile-cache.js:178 Module._compile
    [Webmaster-Portfolio]/[v8-compile-cache]/v8-compile-cache.js:178:30

  - loader.js:712 Object.Module._extensions..js
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10

  - loader.js:600 Module.load
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32

  - loader.js:539 tryModuleLoad
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12

  - loader.js:531 Function.Module._load
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3

  - loader.js:637 Module.require
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17

  - v8-compile-cache.js:159 require
    [Webmaster-Portfolio]/[v8-compile-cache]/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20

  - create-file-node.js:7 Object.<anonymous>
    [Webmaster-Portfolio]/[gatsby-source-filesystem]/create-file-node.js:7:18

  - v8-compile-cache.js:178 Module._compile
    [Webmaster-Portfolio]/[v8-compile-cache]/v8-compile-cache.js:178:30

  - loader.js:712 Object.Module._extensions..js
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10

  - loader.js:600 Module.load
    internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32
```

after I updated some packages I started getting this gastby-cli error. I've never seen it before and its really annoying. Don't know of a solution.

Comment: have you reinstalled `gatsby-cli` globally? or you have always used it in local directory

Comment: Cause: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/14875#issuecomment-503248461

Temporary Solution (not guaranteed to work): run `npm install --save-dev gatsby-cli`

Keep waiting... a fix is on the way: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/14875#issuecomment-503255294

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like something internal to Gatsby broke today, the Dev team is working on it

https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/14875

Answer (score 0):

After I tried everything. 
I uninstalled everything and run
`npm install --save -g gatsby-cli` 
does work for me

Comment: I did try that initially but I will try it again tonight.

Comment: Then try run as administrator your command prompt or if your are on linux try `sudo` at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

try to update `gatsby` version

```sh
npm i gatsby
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same error these days when trying to launch a Starter Template. What worked for me is first to up the version of gatsby on package.json ( "gatsby": "^2.24.42",
). Then just remove the package-lock and do the `npm-install`. On my side that fixed the error.